# How to derive a decision rule as derived from Bayes rule?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, multivariate-normal-distribution, decision-theory

I have a dataset consisting of 5 classes and the prior probability is $p(\omega_c)=\frac{|D_c|}{\sum_{i = 1}^{5}|D_i|}$. Suppose each class $c$ associated with the likelihood $p(x|ω_c)\,=\,\text{N}(\mu_c,\Sigma_c)$.

How can I derive a decision rule using Bayes' rule to assign a sample to one of the 5 classes? Moreover, how can I calculate $P(\text{error}|X)$ and $P(\text{error})$?

Comment: Discriminant analysis

Comment: To build a decision rule one needs a *loss* or *utility* function to weight the consequences of a wrong decision and give a mathematical meaning to the "error". Without these, there is no clear meaning to constructing an *optimal*  decision rule.